# Get resource URL from project specific path

Tags: swift, nsurl, nsfilemanager, nsbundle

I need to retrieve the URL of a resource contained in my Xcode project through a path that begins in the project's directory (aka mainBundle)

So if my specified path if ./snd/archer/acknowledge1.wav, I need to create a URL from that.

I know I can use `NSURL(fileURLWithPath:)` for system directories, but I don't know how to do this directly from the bundle.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You would use one of the bundle resourse URL methods

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"acknowledge1"
                        withExtension:@"wav"
                         subdirectory:@"snd/archer"];

NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("acknowledge1", withExtension:"wav" subdirectory:"snd/archer")
```

*In latest Swift:*

```
Bundle.main.url(forResource: "acknowledge1", withExtension:"wav")
```

Comment: What is the latest swift?

Answer (score 32):

As of Swift 3, the answer is:

```
Bundle.main.url(forResource: "acknowledge1", withExtension: "wav", subdirectory: "snd/archer")
```

Comment: Please fix your answer.  Needs comma before 'subdirectory'.  This is great answer for Swift 4 (& perhaps Swift 3)

Comment: In Swift 4 I needed to provide forResource and withExtension only. When I provided the subdirectory it did not find the .webarchive I was loading (which was in a subdirectory).

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 2.3 you'd have to use this unwrapping:

```
if let resourceUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("acknowledge1", withExtension: "wav", subdirectory:"snd/archer") {
        if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(resourceUrl.path!) {
            print("file found")
            //do stuff
        }
    }
```